# Why cant an SQL query use the instance of a class directly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a program that should basically upload data to a localhost database, XAMPP. The code is working except fr one thing, it does not insert the data specified. It doesn't read the values passed in and therefore fills them in with 0 in the database. This is what puzzles me. I have picked the variables well from the instance of a class yet it does not read them. Why? The variables are not private. I have tried creating an instance of the class on the database class and it still doesn't work. What I don't get is why the variables in the main class cannot be used in the database class.

Main.java

```
package com.healthix;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here

        CollectData instance1 =  new CollectData("James", "Minion", "None","Urine Test","Critical",'M',"22/03/1994","14/05/2019",54789631,25,69,true,true);
        String firstname = instance1.getFirstName();
        String lastname = instance1.getLastName();
        String notes = instance1.getNotes();
        String test = instance1.getTest();
        String refferalReason = instance1.getRefferalReason();
        char gender = instance1.getGender();
        String dateOfBirth = instance1.getDateOfBirth();
        String testDate = instance1.getTestDate();
        int nationalId = instance1.getNationalId();
        int subjectNumber = instance1.getSubjectNumber();
        int result = instance1.getResult();
        boolean resultFromAnalyzer = instance1.isResultFromAnalyzer();
        boolean acceptAsIs = instance1.isAcceptAsIs();
        Database db = new Database();
        db.connectDatabase();
    }


}
```

Database.java

```
package com.healthix;

import java.sql.*;

public class Database {

    public Database() {
        connectDatabase();
    }

    public void connectDatabase() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospitalapi", "root", "");
            Statement stmt = null;
            try {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into Patient(lastname,firstname,notes,test,refferalreason, gender,dateOfBirth,testDate,nationalId,subjectNumber,result,resultFromAnalyzer,acceptAsIs) " +
                    "values(lastname,firstname,notes,test,refferalReason,gender,dateOfBirth,testDate,nationalId,subjectNumber,result,resultFromAnalyzer,acceptAsIs)");


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

CollectData.java

```
package com.healthix;

public class CollectData {

    private String lastName, firstName, notes, test, refferalReason;
    private char gender;
    private String dateOfBirth, testDate;
    private int nationalId = 0, subjectNumber, result;
    private boolean resultFromAnalyzer, acceptAsIs;

    public CollectData(String lastName, String firstName, String notes, String test, String refferalReason, char gender, String dateOfBirth, String testDate, int nationalId, int subjectNumber, int result, boolean resultFromAnalyzer, boolean acceptAsIs) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.test = test;
        this.refferalReason = refferalReason;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.testDate = testDate;
        this.nationalId = nationalId;
        this.subjectNumber = subjectNumber;
        this.result = result;
        this.resultFromAnalyzer = resultFromAnalyzer;
        this.acceptAsIs = acceptAsIs;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public String getRefferalReason() {
        return refferalReason;
    }

    public void setRefferalReason(String refferalReason) {
        this.refferalReason = refferalReason;
    }

    public char getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(char gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getTestDate() {
        return testDate;
    }

    public void setTestDate(String testDate) {
        this.testDate = testDate;
    }

    public int getNationalId() {
        return nationalId;
    }

    public void setNationalId(int nationalId) {
        this.nationalId = nationalId;
    }

    public int getSubjectNumber() {
        return subjectNumber;
    }

    public void setSubjectNumber(int subjectNumber) {
        this.subjectNumber = subjectNumber;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(int result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public boolean isResultFromAnalyzer() {
        return resultFromAnalyzer;
    }

    public void setResultFromAnalyzer(boolean resultFromAnalyzer) {
        this.resultFromAnalyzer = resultFromAnalyzer;
    }

    public boolean isAcceptAsIs() {
        return acceptAsIs;
    }

    public void setAcceptAsIs(boolean acceptAsIs) {
        this.acceptAsIs = acceptAsIs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the sql statement i a string of characters, and you need to convert your objects to such. How about using an ORM such as Hibernate, then you just save the object ?

Comment: You need to go and read about `PreparedStatement` in Java. Currently in your `connectDatabase()` method you don't refer `instance1` in any way, don't expect it to be magically inputted into DB

Comment: Because SQL knows nothing about Java and doesn't need to.

Comment: Even if using the variable names in a query would work (quod non), it wouldn't work in the code you show, because those variables aren't in scope of your query... In any case, you need to read up on prepared statements, or switch to an ORM like Hibernate.

Comment: Alright. i hear you. Thanks for the help. I appreciate.

Comment: So I've checked out PreparedStatement and realised that my parameters were not in the SQL statement. This was very helpful. Here is the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just as I was advised I've checked out PreparedStatement and realised that my parameters were not in the SQL statement. That's why it had nothing to pass into the db. This was very helpful. Here is the code. I also had to add an instance of CollectData.java into Database.java. That's how you'll access the arguments passed in the main method. Here's the final code and a useful resource.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#create_ps

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Database {
    CollectData instance1;

    public Database(CollectData instance1) {
        this.instance1 = instance1;

        connectDatabase();
    }

    public void connectDatabase() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospitalapi", "root", "");
            String loadData = "insert into Patient(lastname,firstname,notes,test,refferalreason, gender,dateOfBirth,testDate,nationalId,subjectNumber,result,resultFromAnalyzer,acceptAsIs) " +
                    "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement updateData = con.prepareStatement(loadData);
            updateData.setString(1,instance1.getLastName());
            updateData.setString(2,instance1.getFirstName());
            updateData.setString(3,instance1.getNotes());
            updateData.setString(4,instance1.getTest());
            updateData.setString(5,instance1.getRefferalReason());
            updateData.setString(6,instance1.getGender());
            updateData.setString(7, instance1.getDateOfBirth());
            updateData.setString(8, instance1.getTestDate());
            updateData.setInt(9,instance1.getNationalId());
            updateData.setInt(10, instance1.getSubjectNumber());
            updateData.setInt(11, instance1.getResult());
            updateData.setBoolean(12, instance1.isResultFromAnalyzer());
            updateData.setBoolean(13, instance1.isAcceptAsIs());

        updateData.executeUpdate();


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```